# Meaning of f{col :-<50}

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, kaggle, eda

I was making a project and then came across this bit of code, i would like to know what is the meaning of the `f'{col:-<50}`

[image].

I have also attached the output of the code, i know that above one is a f statement but am not able to decode it for the specific part.

Answer (score 0):

Your code format the value of `col` (here column name) by alignment with width of 50 characters, padding remaining characters left with `-`, in another words for nicer formating.

```
col = 'class'
print ( f'{col:-<50}')
class---------------------------------------------
```